# Which OCR was used by Google for making Google Books?

Tags: api, google-api, ocr

And especially did they release some API to use it in our development?

I think that an OCR trained over million of books should have simply become perfect and I've also heard that Google improved a lot his algorithm through neural networks for the recognizing of numbers of houses in street view.

So I really wonder if this API are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically for google books , Google customs ocropus opensource OCR with a lot of techniques.

The funniest is the crowdsourcing one via the captchas composed of 2 word, one generated and insuring security, the second one is an unrecognized word in google books or streetview (building numbers) ...

Comment: no, google doesn't think about releasing it as a public API in near future.

Comment: I didn't know this stuff of captcha but it's superfunny